# Updating and using cached ArrayList in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to cache a list of objects that are available for all methods and need it periodically update. I'm wondering if this is safe with multiple threads as per the Spring Boot server. Do I keep the list as static? Or is there a better way to do this?

For example:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    private static List<String> cachedTerms = new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping("/getFirstCachedTerm")
    public String greeting() 
    {
        if(!cachedTerms.isEmpty())
        {
            return cachedTerms.get(0);
        }else
        {
            return "no terms";
        }
    }
    
    //Scheduled to update
    private static void updateTerms()
    {
        //populating from disk IO
        cachedTerms.clear();
        cachedTerms.add("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: No it’s not thread safe. You might `clear` between the `isEmpty` and `get(0)` parts.

Comment: Look into [`BlockingQueue::poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) for a thread safe version with timeout.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you want to always read first element from list then why do you need cache or list? I have used map as a cache before but not able to understand idea behind using list as a cache. Could you explain a bit? Even if you store list of objects then how will you retrieve them. On the basic of index? You can use ```redis``` or ```ehcache``` to implement caching and both of them are thread safe.

Comment: @pcsutar Don't read too much into what the method is about... I'm only using it as an example.  I need to have the list cached to look up items in the list so that I don't have to reload the list from IO every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how. By using CopyOnWriteArray, which can be read even while being altered (and thread safe), and by using the @Scheduled tag to automatically run the update.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    private static final List<String> TERMS_CACHE= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();


    @GetMapping("/FirstTerm")
    public String getFirstTerm() 
    {
       for(String term: TERMS_CACHE)
       {
           return term;
       }
    }
    
    //Scheduled to update
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedRate = 1000)
    private static synchronized void updateTerms()
    {
        //populating from disk IO
        TERMS_CACHE.clear();
        TERMS_CACHE.add("hello");
    }

}
```